# Bayes' theorem, finding the bag the ball was chosen from, $\text{Bag}_1$ or $\text{Bag}_2$

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

$\Pr\left(\text{Blue}|\text{Bag}_1\right) = 0.7$.

$\Pr\left(\text{Blue}|\text{Bag}_2\right) = 0.3$.

I choose balls with replacement from a bag until I have $12$ balls, $8$ of which are blue.

Therefore, the following is my working

$\Pr\left(\text{Blue}|\text{Bag}_x\right) = 0.66$.

But $\Pr\left(\text{Bag}_x|\text{Blue}\right)$ cancels out to $0.66$ using Bayes' Theorem. I'm sure that's wrong right?

Comment: I don't understand what the intended problem is.  You write $\Pr(\text{Blue}\mid\text{Bag}_1)=0.7$.  What does that mean?  That when pulling a ball from the first bag, it is blue with probability $0.7$?  Okay, that is fine for if we were pulling with replacement, but you say *without* replacement.  Are we to assume then that there are a "*large*" number of balls, effectively infinitely many balls?  Why then bother with saying it is without replacement when such a scenario would be better described as having pulled with replacement instead?  If there are not a large number, then how many?

Comment: So then... thinking of it as with replacement instead... we have picked one of the two bags uniformly at random and then picked twelve balls from it with replacement and exactly eight of those twelve balls happened to be blue, we are asking what the probability is that it was the first bag that was selected?  Letting $X$ be the random variable counting number of balls out of twelve that happened to be blue, have you calculated $\Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_1)$ yet?  How about $\Pr(X=8)$?  Recall, the final goal here is (*under my interpretations*) to find $\Pr(\text{Bag}_1\mid X=8)$

Comment: @JMoravitz, we don't know how many balls are in the bags, just the probabilities. I want the probability that my bag was Bag 1 with some steps to reach that solution, I tried playing with the bayes theorem formula but it simplifies to 0.66, which seems too low to me

Comment: @JMoravitz, I also forgot to mention there is replacement

Comment: Share your calculations that you made to get to $0.66$.  Share the values you arrived at for $\Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_1)$ and for $\Pr(X=8)$.  Where specifically in your calculations do you make use of the values $12$, $8$, $0.7$ and $0.3$?

Comment: @JMoravitz, P(Blue|Bag x) = P(Bag x|Blue)*P(Blue)/P(Bag x) 

8/12 = 0.66 = P(Bag x|Blue)*(0.5)/).5

Comment: So... your calculations used only $8,12,$ and $0.5$... where did it use $0.7$?  Where did it use $0.3$?  If it didn't use either then it is very obviously wrong.  You do not seem to have an understanding of what the event "Blue" means in this context.  I'll expand further below.

Comment: As a final nitpick... $\dfrac{8}{12}=\dfrac{2}{3}$ is $0.6666666666666\cdots = 0.\overline{6}$ is not equal to $0.66$.  The fractions $\dfrac{66}{99}$ and $\dfrac{66}{100}$ are not equal... their denominators are not the same.  Do not use equals signs for approximations.  Equals signs are used **only** for equality.  Do not round when you are not told to.  Do not approximate when you are not told to.  Answers should be exact whenever possible, and it is generally acceptable (*or even preferred*) for things to not be fully simplified unless you are explicitly told otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the event "Blue" in your attempt.  This event is illdefined and even if you were to define it properly, it is not at all what we are interested in.  Recall, the problem statement begins "*given that having drawn twelve balls that eight of them are blue...*" or... at least it would begin with this if you had used proper grammar when trying to copy the question.

It is possible that you just could not understand what the question was asking.  Given context clues, I will assume that the correct question is the following:

> We have two bags: Bag 1 and Bag 2.  Bag 1 contains $7$ blue balls and $3$ red balls.  Bag 2 contains $3$ blue balls and $7$ red balls.  We select a bag uniformly at random and then repeatedly draw balls independently and uniformly at random with replacement from the selected bag until we have drawn $12$ in total.  If given that among those twelve balls drawn there were exactly eight of them which were blue, what is the conditional probability that the selected bag happened to be the first one?

Note that what we are conditioning on is the quantity of blue balls of those twelve selected overall... not just the probability of drawing a blue if we were to draw only one ball at a time.  While yes, $\Pr(\text{When drawing one ball, that one ball is blue}\mid \text{Bag}_1)=0.7$ this is very different than $\Pr(\text{When drawing twelve balls, eight of them are blue}\mid \text{Bag}_1)$.

So, let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of the twelve balls drawn which are blue.  Since the balls are drawn with replacement, we recognize that $X$ will be a binomial random variable with $n=12$ and where $p$ will vary depending on which bag we are drawing from.  In the case that we drew from the first bag, $p$ will be $0.7$.  In the case that we drew from the second bag, $p$ will instead be $0.3$.  We have then:

$$\Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_1) = \binom{12}{8}\cdot 0.7^8\cdot 0.3^4$$

$$\Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_2) = \binom{12}{8}\cdot 0.3^8\cdot 0.7^4$$

$$\Pr(X=8) = \Pr(\text{Bag}_1)\cdot \Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_1) +  \Pr(\text{Bag}_2)\cdot \Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_2)$$

The question is asking us for $\Pr(\text{Bag}_1\mid X=8)$.  We approach with Bayes' Theorem and we find:

$$\Pr(\text{Bag}_1\mid X=8) = \dfrac{\Pr(X=8\mid \text{Bag}_1)Pr(\text{Bag}_1)}{Pr(X=8)}$$

Completing the necessary arithmetic finishes the problem.